# What is the probability of the digit $k$ in the number $x^n$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, number-theory, code-request, number-representation

Well, the title of the question says it all: how to write a code that finds the probability of the digit $k$ in the number $x^n$?

For example, when $x=2$, $n=100$, and $k=7$ we are trying to find how many $7$s there are in the number $2^{100}$. To find the answer I wrote $2^{100}=1267650600228229401496703205376$ and counted the number of $7$s, and did:

$$\frac{\text{number of}\space7\text{s}\space\text{in the number}\space2^{100}}{\text{number of digits}\space 2^{100}}=$$
$$\frac{3}{1+\lfloor\log_{10}\left(2^{100}\right)\rfloor}=\frac{3}{31}\approx0.0967742$$

My thoughts for in the code:

- The number of digits in a number $p$ can be found using `1+Floor[Log10[p]]`
- The r'th digit in the number $p$ can be found by using `IntegerDigits[p][[r]]`
- In order to check a table of numbers for there probability we can use `ParallelTable[If[TrueQ[], n, Nothing], {n, ,}]`

> But how to combine the ideas from above, I do not know.

Comment: Thinking along the lines of minimizing memory usage (i.e. avoiding overflow by not actually calculating the power), [`PowerMod`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerMod.html) and the fact that the number of digits of $x^n$ is given by `Floor[n Log10@x] + 1` may be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
countK[x_, n_, k_] := (
  digits = IntegerDigits[x^n];
  Count[digits, k]/Length[digits]
  )
countK[2, 100, 7]
```

Comment: To streamline it a little: `countK[x_, n_, k_] := DigitCount[#, 10, k]/IntegerLength@# &[x^n]`

Answer (score 1):

```
digitFrequency =  NProbability[x == #3, 
   Distributed[x, EmpiricalDistribution @ IntegerDigits[#^#2]]] &;

digitFrequency[2, 100, 7]
```

> ```
>  0.0967742
> ```

```
digitFrequency2 =  N @(AssociationThread @@ Transpose@Tally @ # / Length @ # & @
   IntegerDigits[#^#2]) @ #3 /. _Missing -> 0 &;

digitFrequency2[2, 100, 7]
```

> ```
>  0.0967742
> ```

```
digitFrequency3 = N @ (Divide @@ Through[{Counts, Length}@
     IntegerDigits [#^#2]]) @ #3 /. _Missing -> 0 &;

digitFrequency3[2, 100, 7]
```

> ```
>  0.0967742
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
probs=DigitCount[#]/IntegerLength[#] &;
```

Use:

```
probs[2^100]
```

> {2/31,6/31,2/31,2/31,2/31,5/31,3/31,1/31,2/31,6/31}

The probabilities of digits 1, 2, ..., 9, 0